# Installed addon doesnt show up

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on, layers

i downloaded and installed an addon but when i check it in the preferences it doesn't show up in the panels. Can you help me with that please?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You either need to be in *Pose Mode* or have an armature object selected, otherwise the panel won't be displayed. This happens because the panel implements a `poll()` function that checks for these two conditions.